# problems installing jupyter notebook 7.0.2

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook

I tried installing jupyter notebook 7, it was successfully installed but when I try to launch it I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Python311\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\notebook\app.py", line 17, in <module>
    from jupyterlab.commands import (  # type:ignore
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .handlers.announcements import (
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\handlers\announcements.py", line 15, in <module>
    from jupyterlab_server.translation_utils import translator
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .app import LabServerApp
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\app.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .handlers import LabConfig, add_handlers
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\handlers.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .listings_handler import ListingsHandler, fetch_listings
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\listings_handler.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

any help is greately appreciated

Comment: This error indicates that there is a problem with the encoding of one of the Python files that came with your Jupyter installation - specifically in the `urllib3` library that it will install. Please see the linked duplicate in order to understand the problem, but please do not try to fix it yourself - instead, just try to reinstall. If you cannot make it work then this is a bug to report against the Jupyter notebook installer, not a practical coding problem to answer on Stack Overflow. Unless you *already had* `urllib3` (or `requests`, which would include it) installed.